# Why split() and StringTokenizer() behaving differently

Tags: java, regex, string

```
 public class NewClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
     {
        System.out.println("Operation 1");
        StringTokenizer st1 =
            new StringTokenizer("Hello   Geeks How are you", "\\s+");
            while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
            System.out.println(st1.nextToken());
            String s = "Hello   Geeks How are you";
            String s1[]= s.split("\\s+");
            System.out.println("Operation 2");

            for( String temp : s1) {
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
    }
}
```

Here after executing the code i am getting the output as :-

```
Operation 1
Hello   Geek
 How are you
Operation 2
Hello
Geeks
How
are
you
```

I am not getting why split() and StringTokenizer() behaving differently with same parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `delim` parameter of [`new StringTokenizer(str, delim)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is *not* a regular expression. You are telling `StringTokenizer` to split at *any* of `\`, `s`, or `+`, *not* at "one or more whitespace characters". And the only character this applies to in your string is the "s" in "Geeks", thus that's where the string is split.

If you want to split at whitespaces (one or more), just use the [other constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer-java.lang.String-) taking no `delim` parameter, using `" \t\n\r\f"` as default.

Comment: (just a little tweak I thought made it a little clearer. Feel free to roll back, obvs)